Can we say "I assumed a challenge."?
We can use the phrase "assume responsibility" or "assume power", but can we say "I assumed a challenge", which means "I took a challenge"?
I looked up collocations with challenge on Cambridge Dictionary and this is the list it provided:

These are words often used in combination with challenge.
big challenge; considerable, constitutional, continuing, daunting, difficult, eliminating, engineering, enormous, ethical,  formidable, immense, immunity, intellectual and legal challenge.

There are no results with verbs.
Could anyone please kindly inform me?

What research have you done?

I'm not sure I can explain why, but you typically take on a challenge or accept a challenge. It's much more tangible than responsibility or power.
When you assume responsibility, you become responsible. When you assume power, you become powerful. A challenge is just a different kind of word.

If you Google "assume the challenge" (exact phrase with quotes as here) you see a fair number of what look like examples by educated but non-native speakers, but then you come across this The TU Concurrent Enrollment Program is an opportunity for outstanding students who have taken the most rigorous courses offered by their school to assume the challenge of college course work in specific areas before they graduate from high school. 'TU' is the University of Tulsa, Oklahoma!, USA.

So perhaps it's permissible, but I think "take on" would be much more common.

'Perhaps it's permissible is how I'd put it, too. I don't think I'd use it myself.

Beware: we don't want to set up a formula of "assume X means become X." "Assume the position" breaks this.

I look up "assume the challenge" in Google Books and get a raft of hits from what I assume are non-native speakers, judging from their names, with the meaning "take up the challenge" and a raft of hits from what I assume are native speakers, again judging from their names, where "assume" is a verb complemented by a content clause: "assume (that) the challenge is ..."  I myself would not use the phrase "they eagerly assumed the challenge", which to my ear sounds like something written by someone uncomfortable with phrasal verbs.

Thank you so much!
